# Euler's totient exactly k times

Tags: c++, performance

Given n and k, I need to find Euler's totient exactly k times where n and k are very large numbers. Can anyone help with an optimized solution for a large number?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    return gcd(b%a, a);
}


int phi(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int result = 1;
    for (int i=2; i < n; i++)
        if (gcd(i, n) == 1)
            result++;
    return result;
}

int main() 
{ 
    long n,i,k; 

    cin >>n>>k; 
    long a[n]; 

    for (i=1; i<=k; i++) 
        n = phi(n);

    cout << n<<endl; 

    return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: How large can n and k be?

Comment: n<=10^18, k<=10^18

Comment: I feel like the problem was not stated correctly.  Do you have a link to the original problem?  Why would you need to compute the Euler Totient \$10^{18}\$ times?

Comment: @JS1 Original problem link is (https://www.hackerearth.com/october-clash-16/algorithm/phi-phi-phi/)

Comment: I couldn't open that link but I found this one: [https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/number-theory/totient-function/practice-problems/algorithm/phi-phi-phi/](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/math/number-theory/totient-function/practice-problems/algorithm/phi-phi-phi/).  It seems like your description is right.  You need to recursively call phi k times.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

#### Do prime factorization

Your current `phi()` function is correct but slow.  You would do better by finding the prime factorization of `n` and using the prime factors to calculate `phi`.  Your current `phi()` takes \$O(n)\$ time, but a prime factorization takes \$O(\sqrt n)\$ time.

#### Stop at one

At some point, if `k` is large, you will reach `n` of 1.  At that point you can stop because `phi(1) = 1`.  Actually if at any point `k >= n`, the answer should be 1 because `phi(n)` reduces `n` by at least 1.

Comment: I modified the code according to your answer.  Please check can i improvise it bit more?

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use `namespace std;` this is bad practice and the sooner you stop it the better.
2. Use descriptive names. Even for programming challenges, you can actually use variable names that mean something. This makes the code much easier to understand.
3. Use an stl container in this case most likely `std::vector`. But more important, what is the purpose of `a[n]`, as you do not use it in the code.
4. An `unsigned int` is the same as an `unsigned`
5. `return 0` is superfluous for modern compilers so you can omit it.